# event emiter not working in ErrorHandler inspector

Tags: angular

I want to subscribe to some error event, so i implement the ErrorHandler class:

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    errorSubject = new EventEmitter();
    handleError(error: any) {
        this.errorSubject.emit();
    }
}
```

and the subscription

```
constructor(private errorHandler: ErrorHandler) {
    (errorHandler as GlobalErrorHandler).errorSubject.subscribe(value => () =>{
        // this is never happened
    })
}
```

but the event never fired. how can I get it to work?

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8oprda?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: Consider updating the post with a proper snippet of how you tried using error handler subscription

Comment: Are you including GlobalErrorHandler  in providers somewhere replacing ErrorHandler?

Comment: { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler}

Comment: @yantrab which answer you have accepted, it isn't the right answer, you are not handling the error, it is just throws with broking your actual code

Comment: You did everything right, just change your callback function instead of whole working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only change what you need to do is  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-peixtx?file=src/app/app.module.ts

```
  (this.errorHandler as GlobalErrorHandler).errorSubject.subscribe(error => {
      // this is never happened
      console.log(error, 'why');
    });
```

in your example

```
error => () =>  {
      // this is never happened
      console.log(error, 'why');
}
```

**it should be changed to**

```
error => {
      // this is never happened
      console.log(error, 'why');
}
```

Comment: I have updated the answer, the URL was wrong